# Facebook Timeline Post ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling to find information out there to be able to post / share with an access token.

I followed this tutorial in my MVC app

http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/integrating-facebook-login-button-in-aspnet-mvc-4-application/

and was able to store the access token to my database.

I even went on to try the next tutorial

[http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/posting-to-user's-facebook-wall-in-aspnet-mvc-4/](http://blue-and-orange.net/articles/facebook/posting-to-user's-facebook-wall-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

For this to work you have to log in first and even though got a `403 Forbidden Error`

However, I am not able to figure out on how to post / share to a users Facebook timeline without for them to login again?

Can you without the need to repeatedly login again and with an Access Token post to Facebook?

Comment: Those tutorials are from 2012, and therefor most likely outdated in many ways. Don’t use old resources like that, but always check the official documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed#publish // Hope you are aware that you are not allowed to post on user timelines whenever your app feels like it. The message part of any post/share has to be typed in by the user, and under normal circumstances they should actively trigger each single post (so no “autoposting” or BS like that) – so that normally means that you have a logged-in user anyway.

Comment: @CBroe I am not trying to autopost. I appreciate that the post to individual user profile has to be authorised by user but what I am trying to do is prevent the user from repeatedly logging into Facebook when I have stored their Long Life Access Token ID.

Comment: Basically have a share this link on my web app which is associated to a some content and user can share it on their profile with the help of available access token id

Comment: If you just want to offer users the ability to share certain links, then you can use the Share or Feed dialog – those don’t need any permissions (and therefor not even login to your app), because the user has full control. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

Comment: Yes but I want an extended user token so that they don't have to through the logging in process all the time when they have given access to the app already. A typical example will be sports app where once you only have to log in once within the app and you can share it on your timeline. (Endmondo)

Comment: Then I’d recommend you use the JS SDK for login purposes – that recognizes users that have already logged in to your app before automatically when they visit your site again, and sees to it that you always have a valid access token, no matter how long ago the user’s last visit was. (Or, again, use the dialogs - no login to your app/site necessary at all!)

Comment: You mean something mentioned in here where by getting an extended access token https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nickpinheiro/2015/02/28/facebook-login-with-asp-net-web-forms/

Comment: Found some information in the Facebook API regarding the Posting to a facebook user https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/ If you check the `Publishing` part you will see there is a HTTP POST request to the API `to publish a post on behalf of someone, you would make an HTTP POST request as below:`